# How to export a C program that compiles from command line in Linux to an IDE?

Tags: c++, linux, ide, makefile, export

There are a lot of open source C/C++ projects, most of them can be compiled using "make" in Linux. Is there any easy way to export this to an IDE, for example Microsoft Visual C++, CodeBlock, or Eclipse?
Even if it is an involved work, is there any step by step help for doing that?

Thanks for the help.

TJ

Comment: Eclipse has an option to import an existing project. I have never used it so I cannot speak for how good it is. Eclipse also has tutorial type help guide. You could probably have googled this though.

Comment: You can import a makefile project in VS and Eclipse.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/getting_started/cdt_w_existing_code.htm

Comment: Is this assuming that already there is .proj or .sln file (similar what is in the MS Visual C++)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that most (if not all) of the IDEs support importing a makefile or cmake based project, that should be a no-brainer.

Be careful about configure scripts though, as they generally do important stuff not supported automatically by an IDE.
In fact, build systems like cmake, premake and scons were invented because there was no standard way for an IDE to know what a script is doing. (That, while sacrificing flexibility, makes the system standard.)

Comment: So what is the solution about the configure scripts?

Comment: There isn't one! You've to configure your IDE manually, following what the script does.